# Fix async issue in Node using Billboard API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm a Node noob, trying to write this script to query the Billboard Hot 100 API for ten years of top-10 songs, extracting the top ten songs for each year.

I want to `console.log` the results of the loop -- but the `console.log` statement is executed asynchronously before the loop's done ...

How would one rewrite this so the `console.log` happens *after* the loop is done?

Yeah async baffles me.

```
var billboard = require("billboard-top-100").getChart;
var lyricsText = "List of songs: \n\n";

function getTheSongs() {
  for (let q = 1958; q < 1968; q++) {
    let c = q.toString() + '-07-01';
    billboard('hot-100', c, function(songs) {
      for (let u = 0; u < 10; u++) {
        lyricsText += songs[u].title + ", " + songs[u].artist + "\n";
      }
    }
  )};
  console.log(lyricsText);
}

getTheSongs();
```

Comment: You should look into using promises or `async`/`await`

Comment: And keep in mind that just because you write something from top to bottom, doesn't mean that's the same way everything gets executed